# Doing any sort of exercise too slow recommended?

Tags: muscle-gain, exercise-technique

I need to gain muscle. So I am talking about exercises to gain muscles such as push-ups, pull-ups, push-downs etc.,

My method of doing is keeping relatively more weight and doing very slowly. For suppose I do one push-up for half minute. Like wise I do other exercises. Although none of my friends contradict to it. I saw no one doing like me.

So, my doubt is that whether too much slowness while doing physical exercises cause any issues or recommended?

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing exercises very slow. And very fast. And completely static. And completely normal. You should also be utilizing both heavy weights, and lighter weights, and everything in between.

The point is that you need to challenge your muscles in all the different ways if you want to see progress.

If you do it the same way every time, then your muscles will learn to get really good at that exercise, and they won't need to get bigger or stronger to do it. They just get more effective at doing it.

Comment: To add to this, you want to put your muscles through the full range of motion as well as having long time under tension in order to achieve hypertrophy.